# formula for calculating any angle of an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

This might be an easy question to ask, but for some reason I can not find the right formula to calculate one (does not matter which one) angle (**red**) of an isosceles triangle (**green**).

Here is an example:

**given:**

- triangle `ABE`
- segment `AB` has a length of `2cm` (c)
- segment `BE` has a length of `1.12cm` (a)
- segment `AE` has the same length as segment `BE` (b)

**looking for:**

- either angle `AEB` (gamma)
- or angle `ABE` (beta)
- or angle `BEA` (alpha)

You can find an image of the triangle [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xi7H.png).

---

Lets see what I tried so far.

I found a formula which says:

```
cos. of alpha = ( b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 - a ^ 2 ) / 2 * b * c
```

So I tried:

```
              = ( 1.12 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 2 - 1.12 ^ ) / 2 * 1.12 * 2
              = 6,5088                        / 4,48
              = 1,452857143
```

which is the wrong result.

I found another couple formulas (which I do not remember), but they did not work.

---

**If anyone knows the right formula, I'd be happy to hear it. :)**

Comment: The segment in front of alpha is the segment AB.  You just need to readjust your formula cos of alpha = (a^2+b^2-c^2) / (2*a*b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

draw a line from E to the middle of AB. This is the altitude of an isosceles triangle, so it divides AB in half.

$cos(beta) = 1/1.12$

measure of angle beta = $cos^{-1}(1/1.12) = 26.76°$

Comment: Thank you! This one worked well. Sometimes math can be really hard for me to understand.  :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Notice, you should use the cosine formula as follows $$\cos\alpha=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}=\frac{1.12^2+1.12^2-2^2}{2\cdot 1.12\cdot 1.12}$$